# how i cant change text if radio choose

Tags: php, radio-button

I want if choose google the link text be google.com and if choose facebook the link text facebook.com

this photo explain

```php
 <?php
if (!empty($apps)) {
      foreach ($apps as $cat) {
            ?>
            <div class="col-3" style="text-align: left;">
                  <input type="radio" name="site_app_cat" value="<?= $cat->cat_id; ?>" onclick="show_temp(this.value);">
                  <span><?= $cat->cat_name; ?></span>
                  <img src="<?= base_url() ?>/asset/other/caticons/<?= $cat->icon_name ?>" class="cticon_footer" style="margin-top: 0px;">
            </div>
<?php
      }
} else { }
?>
<br>
<b><?= form_error('site_app_cat', '<p style="color: #ff4040;font-style: italic;">', '</p>'); ?></b>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;text-align: left;">
      <h7 style="color: green">site link <h7>
                  <span style="font-size: 12px;color: red;"></span>
            </h7>
</div>
<div class="row">
      <input type="text" name="site_link" class="form-control1" id="focusedinput" placeholder="enter site link" value="<?= set_value('site_link'); ?>" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 5px;padding: 5px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 10px;">
      <b><?= form_error('site_link', '<p style="color: #ff4040;font-style: italic;">', '</p>'); ?></h7>
</div>
<?
```

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wizrt.png

Comment: You will need JavaScript / AJAX to achieve this; you can't use PHP to update the document without a refresh.

Comment: onclick event that you added will call show_temp(value) JavaScript function. That is where you want to select element with id focusedinput (or by name site_link) and change the value to one passed from variable value previously